# How to show collapse/expand button beside a sub-group in Excel that is the last child of it's parent?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am experiencing this strange behaviour in Excel and am looking for either an explanation or a solution.

I am using Excel's grouping feature to create some parent-child nodes within my spreadsheet. When you do this, Excel normally adds a plus/minus button alongside the nodes to allow you to expand/collapse each grouping.

However, I have noticed that whenever my sub-group is at the bottom of its parent (i.e. it is the last child in the grouping) Excel does not show the button. Why is this?

Button not showing on sub-group that is the last child of its parent:
[image: Button not showing on sub-group that is the last child of it's parent]

Button **is** showing on sub-group that is **not** the last child of its parent
[image: Button IS showing on sub-group that is NOT the last child of it's parent]

Answer (score 1):

Add a blank line below the last sub-grouping, then ungroup & re-group again.  It should now show the + for last sub-group.  This works so long as you can live with the extra blank line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the problem still remains for a sub-group that is the last child. Adding the extra line at the bottom as you say makes the sub-group no longer the last child!

Answer (score -1):

Untick the ‘Summary rows below detail’:

[image]

http://www.auditexcel.co.za/blog/group-ungroup-move-the-plus-and-minus-icon-to-the-top/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it seems to just "flip" the effect. It adds the child sign but actually removes the top level minus sign!